# Docker bridge and Falcon gunicorn

Tags: docker, gunicorn, falcon

I would like to run on EC2 instance simple API build in Falcon and gunicorn. I would like to access that API from docker container installed on that host over bridge (docker0 IP 172.17.0.1).

I am running API application by using gunicorn command:

gunicorn -b 172.17.0.1:8000 simple-api:api

I can ping that IP address from docker and I can telnet to port 8000 but when I execute curl POST command I am getting following error:

```
 < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 * Server gunicorn/19.7.1 is not blacklisted
 < Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
 < Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 08:26:01 GMT
 < Connection: close
 < content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
 < content-length: 0
 <
 * Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I had a typo in POST requests.